# Quick Sort in Swift is giving error

Tags: swift, swift3

I am writing a Quick Sort using higher order function in Swift but it is giving

```
error: 'Int' is not convertible to '[Int]'
return quickSort(array: lesser) + [pivot] + quickSort(array: greater)
```

Here is the code:

```
func quickSort(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var array = array

    if array.isEmpty {return []}

    let pivot = array.remove(at: 0)
    let lesser = array.filter { $0 < pivot }
    let greater = array.filter { $0 >= pivot }

    return quickSort(array: lesser) + [pivot] + quickSort(array: greater)

}
```

Error is in the last line.

Comment: For what's worth it, I just tested your [code on Linux](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net) and error remains the same — cross platform at its best ;-)

Comment: Thanks @PauloMattos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you why it does not work (I think it should), but I can tell you how to fix it

Replace this

```
return quickSort(array: lesser) + [pivot] + quickSort(array: greater)
```

with this

```
return
    quickSort(array: lesser) as [Int] +
    [pivot] +
    quickSort(array: greater)
```

Comment: I have editied your answer to add one more syntactic sugar to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed the compiler getting confused with data types in a multi operation formula involving the return type of the function it is currently compiling.

There are probably a multitude of ways to help the compiler along .  Here's one that doesn't involve redundant type casting (the key is making pivot an [Int] array):

```
func quickSort(array: [Int]) -> [Int] 
{
    if array.count < 2 { return array }

    let pivotValue = array.first!  
    let lesser     = array.filter{ $0 < pivotValue }
    let greater    = array.filter{ $0 > pivotValue }
    let pivot      = Array(repeating: pivotValue, 
                               count: array.count - lesser.count - greater.count) 

    return  quickSort(array:lesser) + pivot + quickSort(array:greater)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```
func partition(_ inputArray: [Int], startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int)-> (Int, [Int]) {
    var array = inputArray
    var index = startIndex
    if startIndex < endIndex {
        let pivot = array[endIndex]

        for demo in startIndex..<endIndex {
            if array[demo] <= pivot {
                (array[index], array[demo]) = (array[demo], array[index])
                index += 1
            }
        }
        (array[index], array[endIndex]) = (array[endIndex], array[index])

    }
   return (index, array)
}


func QuickSort(_ input: [Int], startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int)-> [Int] {
    var array = input
    if startIndex < endIndex {
         let pivot = partition(array, startIndex: startIndex, endIndex: endIndex)
       let index = pivot.0
        array = pivot.1
       array = QuickSort(array, startIndex: startIndex, endIndex: index-1)
        array = QuickSort(array, startIndex: index+1, endIndex: endIndex)
    }
    return array
}
```